# Doing a factory reset on a laptop

Tags: windows

My laptop used to come with windows 10, but then I decided to install ubuntu on it instead. Now I would like to install windows 10. Is there way to get windows 10 back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need a bootable USB - a USB flash drive that has at least 16GB of space (there are free programs that you will find available on internet to make the USB bootable), download  Windows 10 ISO file and add to the USB.
Alter the BIOS sequence on your PC so your USB device is first. In most instances, the BIOS will usually not be automatically set to your device. If you skip this step, your computer will start regularly from your hard drive instead of getting boot information from your USB device, then follow the steps to install the windows OS.